# Would metal bullets be more effective against a lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

I've been wondering, we always see lightsabers reflecting blaster lasers which, supposedly, are raw energy. We get no indication that there is actually any substance to a lightsaber's blade, so wouldn't a bullet just go straight through it, melt, and then plaster the Jedi's face with molten metal?

Or is there a fact I'm missing?

(We see that lightsaber blades melt metal, not vaporize it into steam, but even if that was the case I don't think a face full of metal steam would do you much good either.)